# JQuery: for condition is not able to complete due to .replaceWith manipulation

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, parsing, replacewith

I am trying to get a line of JQuery script to read every paragraph string found in a div and split that paragraph every time there is a ','. My issues is that I am unable to POST all of the array at once, so the replaceWith function only outputs the first value of the array because the rest of the array is deleted when the for condition returns to increment to myArray[1].

Is there anyway for me to post every value in the 'array of splits' to separate html elements without leaving the initial string and/or turning every created element a child of the previous element?

DEMO
http://jsfiddle.net/ry25Q/

HTML

```
    <div class="data">
        <i>days_of_week</i>
        <p>mon,tue,wed,thur,fri,sat,sun</p>
    </div>
      <div>
        <input type="button" class="btnClick Button" value="Click" />
     </div>
```

JS CODE

```
$(function () {
    $('.btnClick').click(function () {
        var data = $('.data p').text();
        var splitter = data.split(',');
        for (var i = 0; i < splitter.length; i++) {
            $(".data p").replaceWith("<span class='dataseg'>" + splitter[i] + "</span>")
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I don't get this at all? What exactly are you trying do?

Comment: @adeneo _thank goodness_. I thought it was just me!

Comment: Is this it -> http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/ry25Q/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a loop. Since you're only replacing one `p` element, just call `.replaceWith()` once with the full HTML string you're inserting.

***DEMO:*** http://jsfiddle.net/Vfk4e/

```
$(function () {
    $('.btnClick').click(function () {
        var p = $('.data p');
        var splitter = p.text().split(',');

        var open = "<span class='dataseg'>";
        var close = "</span>"

        p.replaceWith(open + splitter.join(close + open) + close)
    });
});
```

Comment: Clean and short. Worked like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just add `$('.data p').text('');` before your `for` statement?  This will clear the contents,t hen your `.append` from your fiddle will work just fine.

```
$(function () {
    $('.btnClick').click(function () {
        var data = $('.data p').text();
        var splitter = data.split(',');

        $('.data p').text('');

        for (var i = 0; i < splitter.length; i++) {
            $(".data p").append("<span class='dataseg'>" + splitter[i] + "</span>")
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I get undefined when I do that because of my [i] varaible. I really wish I could just put a [*] and have my entire array addressed.

Comment: It worked in the jsfiddle though.  I'll edit my answer to what I had in your fiddle.

Comment: `i`? `[*]`? _What are you talking about?_

Answer (score 1):

Try to create a variable for the `span` element you wish to replace the `<p>` element with.  Then inside of your for loop, sequentially add your data to the `span` element.  After the loop, close your span and then call replaceWith() with the span variable.

```
$(function () {
    $('.btnClick').click(function () {
        var data = $('.data p').text();
        var splitter = data.split(',');
        var daySpan = "<span class='dataseg'>";

        for (var i = 0; i < splitter.length; i++) {
            daySpan += splitter[i]; 
        }

        daySpan += "</span>";

        $(".data p").replaceWith( daySpan );
    });
});
```

Demo:  http://codepen.io/imajedi4ever/pen/kpzCD/?editors=101

Comment: This places all of the array under one element. My primary problem was figuring out a way of doing what Cookie and James did without having long code since I'm using this for a node.js web scraping project. Thanks for answering.